# Roundcube with Vesta CP - plugins activation is not working

Tags: php, linux, imap, roundcube, vesta

I've created a simple plugin for RoundCube. It adds custom headers to all sent messages. All files were uploaded to this folder `/usr/share/roundcube/plugins`. BUT, I've found the same folders structure here `/etc/roundcube/plugins/`. There are only plugins names and config files in there folders (like `/etc/roundcube/plugins/password/config.inc.php`).
All changes I`m doing in a standart plugins here`/usr/share/roundcube/plugins` were affected the system BUT only for preinstalled plugins.

I`m totally confused why it is detecting preinstalled folders and not detecting new ones.

I`ll highly appreciate any help.

PC: all folders are assigned to the same user, EXAMPLE: `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Sep 12 19:43 password`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VestaCP has 3 folders for Roundcube plugins:

- `/usr/share/roundcube/plugins` - all files
- `/etc/roundcube/plugins/` - configuration files
- `/var/lib/roundcube/plugins` - links to a real files

You can solve this problem creating a link to `/usr/share/roundcube/plugins` in a main folder: `/var/lib/roundcube/plugins`.